# XCode 8: basic MKMapView causes warnings

Tags: ios, mkmapview, xcode8

In an XCode 8 Swift 3 project, I have a ViewController that contains nothing but a MKMapView. Whenever I segue to this ViewController, I get the following warning printout...

```
MyProject[2141:497518] [LogMessageLogging] 6.1 <private>
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader


Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
```

I don't know why this happening nor how to resolve it. This is simply a ViewController with a map, nothing more, so I don't see why there are these problems.

Comment: Me too, I have posted questions too. Still not any answers. But it seems only warning message which haven't cause any issues.

Comment: any 1 have answer?i m facing it too...no clue

Comment: May be this will be helpful `https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/cant-see-any-segmented-control/11165/2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue in my app. But I noticed that this issue is related to `MKMapType` and `Zooming` the map i.e. `Standard` and `Hybrid` `MKMapType` shows this error when you set **region** of map view or **zoom** map view. I solved this by changing the `MKMapType` `Standard` to `Satellite` and this is happing only when app test on simulator but in real device there is no such kind of warning. Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: This issue happing in devices also and your answer not opt to fix it

Comment: @BalakrishnanMca Why down vote ? I'm not forcing any one to do the same as i do. I'm just suggesting because this solves my problem may be this can help any other one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you  forget to write the "[self.manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];"
this method is a method of CLLocationManager;

Comment: and you have to write a key in the info.plist ,and the key you can find at the method explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
          let locManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Was getting the exact same warning/breakpoint which made my app stop. I am not 100 percent sure why but adding this after the creation of my locManager did the trick.

```
         locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Reason could be

1. The locManager access to your location might have being denied at some point in time and you need to always ask so that another user has the chance of accepting.
2. You never asked for it. If you ask once and the user accepts your map will always work fine.

You might have to restart your app. That's what I had to do.

The other thing I noticed is that this message is related to your Phone Carrier being Private (In my case was none as I don't have a chip on my iphone). In the other hand when my carrier had a carrier(Sprint,etc) it worked. Still not sure why but hopefully this give you an starting point. But I believe the carrier has nothing to do with the location manager though.